# AJAX not working with cached iPhone webapp

Tags: jquery, ajax, application-cache

I just made an offline iPhone webapp with the application cache.
But the AJAX-calls made with the cached JS-file don't work anymore.
It are just jQuery GET requests. They fail to work, but why?

I have internet connection, the webapp needs to update when there is internet, and when there is no internet it gets it's data from a cache.

+

Tried with bare bones ajax too, doesn't work... I get empty response.

Anyone know this problem, and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this but here a link with some more info about [safari cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH4-SW1)

It seems that you can specify which elements of the app you want to cache, and also how to update the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this too.

Include a NETWORK: section in your manifext file that include your site. Ajax calls should work after that.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this? Be more specific.
What to place under the `NETWORK:` part? What do you mean with "your site"